# Best practices for NTP updating in VirtualBox virtual machines without guest additions?

Tags: virtualbox, ntp

I have a couple of VMs that cannot have guest additions installed, and I pause and resume them  with days between. I normally forget to nudge NTP when I start up the VM. Is there a good way to tell ntp to be very aggressive in how often it should check for changes?

Answer (score 5):

I know you said you couldn't install them, but it's worth saying that the machine additions were created (at least partially) to solve this problem; and should be the solution.

`ntpd` can only be set to ignore wild offsets at startup; so you'll have to configure the machines to run `ntpdate` via `cron` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The [Vmware suggested](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1006427) NTP configuration for a similar issue will almost certainly apply here.

You need to set the `tinker panic 0`.  Make sure your system is not using the local clock as a high stratum server.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an option to attach `ntpdate` to network interface up event, which is triggered on guest resume ( `man devd` for FreeBSD )